# changing element>element style inside javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have this style showing a card, and I want to change it inside the function after picking the card. how can I use style.background = '#FFF'; on `div#memory_board > div` type?

```
div#memory_board > div{
background:black;
border:#000 1px solid;
width:71px;
height:71px;
float:left;
margin:10px;
padding:20px;
font-size:64px;
cursor:pointer;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: for me it's better to use class for picked elements

Comment: @MrJ Can you please provide example?

Comment: can you provide more  html code ?

Comment: it's way too much code. just the part of necessary to the problem is useful, the rest is a polution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the following to your CSS, which would be applied to the "picked" card `<div>`:

```
div#memory_board > div.picked {
 background: #fff;
}
```

Once you've added the above to your style sheet, you would then add the `picked` class to the `<div>` elements directly under `#memory_board` element which would produce the desired visual result.

```
<div id="memory_board">
    <div></div> <!-- regular style -->

    <div></div> <!-- regular style -->

    <div class="picked"></div> <!-- regular style with "picked" appearance -->
</div>
```

#### Update

To apply the `picked` class to the clicked `<div>` you need to update your `cardIsSelected()` function in your script:

```
 function cardIsSelected(event, letter)
 { 
    /* This will cause "picked" class to be added to the div being 
       clicked */
    event.currentTarget.classList.add('picked');

    /* Leave existing code */
 }
```

You will also need to pass the `event` object to `cardIsSelected` by updating this line of your code as well:

```
output += '<div id="card'+i+'" onclick="cardIsSelected(event, \''+memory_array[i]+'\')">'+memory_array[i]+'</div>';
```

Here is a [working CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLjdGL?editors=1000)

Comment: inside the `<script>` in the html

Comment: yes just make sure you pass it in like this `checkResult(event);` and then extend `function checkResult(event) { .. }`